# Best way to transfer data from source table in one db to destination table in another db daily

Tags: sql

What would be the best way to transfer certain number of records daily from source to destination and then remove from source?

DB - SQL server on cloud.

Comment: The source is SQL Server on cloud, what is the destination?

Comment: The source and destination both are on Azure cloud, in different Databases on same server.

Comment: I haven't used SQL Server in the cloud yet, they are on the same server, you mean they are one beside the other, like this? https://prnt.sc/vzBxNVatA8tO

Comment: No, They are in different databases. The source table is temporal history table. The history tables grows very large. We want to device a mechanism to slowly transfer data from history table to another table in another DB which is not connected to application.

Comment: In the print that I showed you, there are 2 different databases on the same server: https://prnt.sc/y6ua0kijLLuN your structure is like this?

Comment: _Monitor and Paulo are different databases in the same server

Answer (score 0):

As the databases are in the same server, you can create a job that transfers the data do the other database.

[image]

Because the databases are in the same server you can easily access them, just by adding the database before the table in the query, look the test that i did:

```
CREATE DATABASE [_Source]
CREATE DATABASE [_Destination]

CREATE TABLE [_Source].dbo.FromTable
(
some_data varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE [_Destination].dbo.ToTable
(
some_data varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO [_Source].dbo.FromTable VALUES ('PAULO')

--THE JOB WOULD BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

-- INSERT INTO DESTINATION GETTING THE DATA FROM THE SOURCE
INSERT INTO [_Destination].dbo.ToTable
SELECT some_data 
FROM [_Source].dbo.FromTable

-- DELETE FROM SOURCE
DELETE [_Source].dbo.FromTable
```

Comment: The databases are in Azure cloud. We cannot access one db from another in cloud.